# Ubuntu 18.04 hangs after "iwlwifi message no beacon heard" no kubuntu splash screen

Tags: boot, 18.04, nvidia, iwlwifi

I just installed a new SSD for Windows 10; Ubuntu resides on my 2nd HDD. Set the bios to boot to grub menu and before splash screen even appears I get an error message "...iwlwifi...no beacon heard and the timed event is over already" then the cursor sits flashing and system hangs. Earlier I had fixed an issue where after splash screen often Ubuntu would not load to login screen (Nvidia drivers)  so I added "nomodeset" to quiet splash and it booted to login screen and Ubuntu worked fine, so I assume that fixed that issue and is not relevant to this one. Then I proceeded with the new disk install. I have gone root and used `lspci` and `dmesg | grep firmware` and am not sure how to make sense of the output. Should I put the old SSD with Windows back in and see if the problem persists or is there something else causing this? I am on a Cybertron PC Intel i7-6400 Intel HD Graphics 530/Nvidia GTX 965 and 24 gb ram.

[image]

[image]